# 3 columns layout with rightmost column wrapping under middle one if too narrow

Tags: html, css

I want to create a 3-column layout with fixed-width left and right column, and middle column taking the rest of the space. That's pretty easy. Now I want the middle column to have a min-width, and the rightmost column to wrap **under** the middle column if the total width is too small.

This is the normal layout:

```
+----------+ +------------------------------+ +--------------------+
|   LEFT   | |        MIDDLE (main)         | |       RIGHT        |
+----------+ +------------------------------+ +--------------------+
```

This is the layout under a certain total width:

```
+----------+ +-------------------------+
|   LEFT   | |      MIDDLE (main)      |
|          | +-------------------------+
|          | +--------------------+
|          | |       RIGHT        |
+----------+ +--------------------+
```

- I don't mind changing the order of the DIVs in the HTML.
- I don't mind wrapping DIVs in extra DIVs.

Comment: could you use @media queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this: http://jsfiddle.net/X3tPJ/

"Right" will wrap under "Main", but those two won't wrap under "Left".

Comment: Thanks. I did change the sample to reflect my need to not force a full height of the left column and have a max-width on the middle. Works well! http://jsfiddle.net/X3tPJ/4/

Answer (score 0):

[I made a fiddle that has the three columns.](http://jsfiddle.net/c6Nkj/) It groups the middle and right columns together and floats it next to the left column. Take a look and see if it does what you need.

Comment: Unfortunately, the middle and right columns wrap under the left one if the width is really small (think mobile devices), and you're cheating with the left column height. With an undetermined height, the right column ends up wrapping at the very left. :(

Answer (score 0):

Semantically, you're actually best off setting up your content like this:

```
<div id="main">
...
</div>
<div class="sidebar" id="sidebar-left">
...
</div>
<div class="sidebar" id="sidebar-right">
...
</div>
```

Check out [this article on negative margins](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/negativemargins/) to see how to get this technique to work.

I recommend this technique over the others for a few reasons. My main reason for choosing this method is that by doing this, your content actually starts loading *before* your sidebars do. There are also some benefits to SEO that you gain from placing your Content before your sidebars.